# React.js Frontend/ ASP.NET API backend : How do I use ADFS/OpenID Connect?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, adfs

Hi I'm developing currently a full stack web application for an organization, and I was tasked to use and apply ADFS and OpenID connect for authentication purposes.
I've been reading some docs and I don't understand where I need to authenticate, on the front end side or on the backend side.
I also can't find any examples for an react/.net app that uses adfs-openid authentication so i would be very grateful if any could help point me in the right direction.

Cheers,

From what I understand the authentication should happen on the react web app and then when calling the api the token should be verified but I would like to see examples of implementation

Comment: You can review this microsoft article at once as its for single page application : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.